# LibreOffice 4.4.1.2 - Can't install "Help for Offline Use" on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: libreoffice, offline

I have LibreOffice 4.4.1.2 installed and working on my PC running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

But, the LibreOffice "Help" icon brings me to the LibreOffice site. It does NOT launch any Help files within the LibreOffice Application itself.

I have downloaded the LibreOffice 4.4.1.2 "Help for Offline Use" files from their site, and "extracted" them onto my computer. But, I cannot find any way to install the Help files so they are accessible.

Can anyone explain how to install or make the LibreOffice 4.4.1.2 "Help for Offline Use" accessible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install libreoffice-help package, for example:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-help-en-us
```

The help language must be the same as the UI language. To check which is the language of user Interface, go to Tools -> Options -> Language Settings.

Comment: That got "Help" working from inside the application, but for some reason, images within "Help" are not displaying. Do you know how to solve that issue? I did try restarting my PC, but that didn't make any difference.